# Grabbing local files from drag and drop event and displaying them

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to grab dragged and dropped files from the drop event and displaying the images in an area just so the user knows that the drop was successful. However, I'm unsure how to grab those dropped files and display them in an area. I've attempted to that like so:

```
$(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files).each(function(){
    $("#feedBackAreaTest").append("<img src='"+this.name+"' />");
});
```

However, it only grabbed the name, obviously. My question is, what is the right way of displaying the images dropped? `this.name` is only grabbing the name and not the link to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File` objects are like oysters: you can inspect them superficially, but you can't know what they *really* have in them until you pry them open and look inside. To do that, you need to use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to extract the data from each `File` object:

```
$(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files).each(function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this);
    reader.onload = function(readEvent) {
        $("#feedBackAreaTest").append("<img src='"+readEvent.target.result+"' />");
    }
});
```

[`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) objects have a few read methods that each take a `Blob` or `File` object as an argument (`readAsText`, `readAsDataURL`, etc.). When the read operation is done, the `FileReaader` fires a `load` event which has the data from the file just read.

Comment: Strangely enough, I get this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FileReader`

Comment: @Majed [`FileReader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) is part of the W3C's [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) draft specification. It is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/filereader) in most recent browsers (especially among those that also support [drag and drop](http://caniuse.com/dragndrop)). Notably, it is **not supported** in IE 9 or earlier.

Comment: I thought file reader was a native javascript function just like `new XMLHttpRequest();` and `new FormData();` which appears to be the case. Thanks @apsillers

Comment: Just know, that the code is a little bit wrong. Instead of `readAsDataUrl()` it is `readAsDataURL()` Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the FileReader API; I pulled this sample from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) that you can use:

```
var oFReader = new FileReader(), 
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
    $("#feedBackAreaTest").append("<img src='"+oFREvent.target.result+"' />");
};

function loadImageFile() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { 
    return; 
    }
    var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { 
        alert("You must select a valid image file!"); 
        return; 
    }
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```