# How to put an image in a javascript localstorage entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm working with javascript localstorage right now to create an app in which you can create entries with a title, image, description and location. Everything works fine, except I can't figure out how to handle the image. This is the code i use to create an entry:

```
var json_entry = {'title': titleField.val(),
                  'image': $("#image").val(),
                  'content': contentField.val(),
                  'location': location};
```

As you can see now I'm simply using the value of the file field. Which puts a fake path in my entry. Obviously handling images with localstorage isn't as simple as i thought. Could anyone give me a code sample of how I can make this work?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718333/710446 (put that code inside of a `$("#image").change` handler)

Answer (score 1):

Store that whole object in the localStorage (stringified of course):

```
localStorage.setItem(imageEntry, JSON.stringify(json_entry));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not completely sure how I would implement this in the code given above?

Comment: You can store each image entry object into localStorage, and call that back then on page load.

Comment: So something like this?: 'image': localStorage.setItem(imageEntry, JSON.stringify($("#image").val()));,

Comment: How are using the above object in your original post to set images?

Comment: I use a form field for the use to choose an image

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this due to security reasons. You'd have to upload the image and store the url to the uploaded image.

You might be able to look into storing a base64 version of the image in localStorage using the File API. [Here's quick tutorial on it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Think about it, if you could store a path to a file on a users machine and call it when you want you can very easily request something like `C:\My Documents\Sensitive Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was so late to help here.

```
var json_entry = [];

json.push({
           title: titleField.val(),
           image: $("#image").val(),
           content: contentField.val(),
           location: location
          });

localstorage.setItem("imageDetail", JSON.stringify(json));
```